# Get to know which picturebox was clicked

Tags: vb.net

In my current VBA project I have several pictureboxes which will activate a messagebox when you click on one of them. Is there any way for me to get to know which of the pictureboxes was clicked? I've added the code I have currently which doesnt allow me to pass any information to the sub so each picturebox will active the exact same message.

```
AddHandler newPictureBox.Click, AddressOf pic_Click

Public Sub pic_Click()
   MsgBox("test")
End Sub
```

Comment: are you using VBA? or VB.NET? state the correct tags of programming language you use...

Comment: I use Visual Basic 2010 express. Im actually not sure which one it is or what the difference is.

Comment: If you use VB 2010 Express, then you're using VB.NET. VBA is the Visual Basic flavor that's used in Microsoft Office.

Comment: If you used Option Strict On, you would get a warning "Method 'Public Sub pic_Click()' does not have a signature compatible with delegate 'Delegate Sub EventHandler(sender as Object, e as System.EventArgs)'" which would have given you a hint that the sender is passed to the event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see above you are using VB2010.  Try this...

```
AddHandler newPictureBox.Click, AddressOf pic_Click

Private Sub pic_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim thisPic As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
    'thisPIC now is a reference to the box, you can use .Name, etc. to get it's properties.
End Sub
```

Comment: directcast was the thing I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a different handler to each picturebox, which would then delegate to another sub, passing along the info about which picturebox was clicked.

Comment: Thats quite impractical as these pictureboxes are created based on certain files in a folder so I never know which pictureboxes will exist.

Comment: @JanmetdekorteAchternaam I see. Perhaps you could use a lambda function as a handler? See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204801/how-to-declare-lambda-event-handlers-in-vb-net

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the **picturebox.click** event?
Just double click on your picturebox and it will automatically be using that event.
Then you can add your own code into the picturebox.click so they will have their own function.

If that's not what you want, please describe what it is that you're trying to do more clearly.